# Shortest sequence that contains a given list of sequences as subsequences

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, approximation-algorithms, permutations, string-matching

Given an alphabet with $n$ characters, and a list $L$ of sequences can we approximately find  the shortest sequence that contains all sequences of $L$ as subsequences?

Very similar to the question here
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165303/shortest-supersequence-of-all-permutations-of-n-elements

Comment: See the paper [On the Approximation of Shortest Common Supersequences and Longest Common Subsequences](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S009753979223842X?journalCode=smjcat)