# How well can shortest common supersequence over small alphabet size be approximated?

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, approximation-algorithms, permutations, string-matching

Given a list $L$ of sequences of the first $n+1$ natural numbers, how well can we approximate the shortest common supersequence of all sequences in $L$?  The paper here shows that if $n$ is not restricted there is no constant factor polynomial time approximation.
[On the Approximation of Shortest Common Supersequences and Longest Common Subsequences](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S009753979223842X?journalCode=smjcat)

Does this remain true if $n$ is bounded or small say sublinear in $L$?

Comment: Related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/54062/8237

Comment: @NealYoung  Mapping doesn't work because we're looking at subseqences not substrings.
If we try to map the set of charactersonto $k$ ary strings then choosing a minimum set  i(0),i(1),.., i(k)  of the first n+1 natural numbers such that   b_i(0),b_i(1),.., b_i(k)  contains each of 0,1,2,..,k    then (b_i(0) b_i(1) .., b_i(k) )^* contains a supersequence of any  sequence

Comment: @NealYoung  I'm not looking for a PTAS there are two "constants" in question the approximation ratio and the alphabet size.  My question is there any $b \geq 0$ such that for any constant $c \geq 2 $ the SCS problem on an alphabet of size c admits a $b$-approximation?

Comment: Actually it's  "is there a constant b  such that for  ANY constant c≥2 , the c
-supersequence problem is NP-hard to approximate within b?

Comment: Hao, and I assume by "for ANY constant c" you mean "for ALL constants c", not "for SOME constant c."  So, you are asking "does there exist  a constant b such that, for every fixed c, b-approximating the c-supersequence problem (with running time polynomial in the input size, but depending arbitrarily on c and b) is NP-hard?"

Comment: @NealYoung  Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152322/discussion-between-neal-young-and-hao-s).

Answer (score 1):

> Does this remain true if $n$ is bounded?

No.  When $n=O(1)$, there is a constant-factor approximation algorithm.  See Lemma 1 below.

> Does this remain true if $n$ is sublinear in $|L|$?

Yes. For every constant $\epsilon>0$,
the problem remains just as hard to approximate
even when $n\le |L|^{\epsilon}$.
See Lemma 2 below.

---

**Lemma 1.** *There is a constant-factor approximation algorithm for the case when $n=O(1)$.*

**Lemma 2.** *For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$
such that, if the problem (restricted to $n\le |L|^{\epsilon}$)
has a polynomial-time approximation algorithm with performance ratio $n^\delta$, then P=NP.*

*Proof of Lemma 1.* Just return the sequence $$(1, 2, \ldots, n+1)^\ell$$ where $\ell=\max\{|\sigma| : \sigma \in L\}$.
This sequence has length $(n+1)\ell$,
while $\ell$ is a lower bound on the optimum,
so this is an $(n+1)$-approximation algorithm.
$~~\Box$

*Proof of Lemma 2.*
Fix any $\epsilon>0$.
We point out that the general problem reduces
in polynomial time, preserving approximate solutions,
to the restricted problem (requiring $n \le |L|^\epsilon$).

Given an instance $(L, n)$ of the general problem,
the reduction produces the instance $(L_\epsilon, n)$
where $L_\epsilon$ is obtained from $L$
by adding $n^{1/\epsilon}$ empty sequences, so that
$$|L_\epsilon| \ge n^{1/\epsilon}, \text{ that is } n\le |L_\epsilon|^\epsilon,$$
so that $(L_\epsilon, n)$ is indeed an instance of the restricted problem.

We assume WLOG here that every symbol in $[n+1]$ occurs in some string in $L$, so $n$ is at most the input size $\sum_{\sigma\in L} |\sigma|$, so the reduction takes polynomial time.

By the result cited by OP,
there is a $\delta>0$
such that there is no poly-time $n^{\delta}$-approximation
algorithm for the general problem
unless P=NP.
By the above reduction
(which blows up the input size by at most a polynomial)
the same is true for the restricted problem.
$~~~~\Box$

Comment: I meant a constant independent of n.

Comment: Which constant do you mean should be independent of $n$?  And what does "independent of $n$" mean if we are restricting $n$ to be $O(1)$?

Comment: Is there a constant c such that for any n,   given a list $L$ of sequences of the first $n+1$ natural numbers,  we can approximate the shortest common supersequence of all sequences in $L$? within factor c in time polynomial in |L|?
In other words first fix the the approximation ratio then fix n.

Comment: I don't see how $n$ is "fixed" as you describe it.  Could you make all the quantifiers you have in mind explicit?

Comment: Do you understand the statement before "in other words"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152242/discussion-between-neal-young-and-hao-s).